# Mobile DB app off line from internet

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have an architecture question.  If you have a web app that is storing information on a DB server, theoretically, I should be able to use the middle tier logic for a mobile app.  When the mobile app starts it can connect and populate a local SQLite DB or use JSON to store information within the mobile app.  What if the mobile app also needs to work in off-line mode?  Do you have it sync the next time it is connected?  Do you have the mobile pull down and populate a complete DB or so it available in off-line?  What are the best ways to architect a mobile app that has to go from on-line to off-line?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to put a "LastEdited" column into every table in your database and then pull query all the data which has updated since the last sync ( and you can perform a check on the index to detirmine if you need to update or insert into your own local cache. ) 
The ability to delete rows should actually be limited to a boolean "isDeleted" flag in this case to keep the sync process nice and simple.

If you have then the ability to edit or create rows from your app then you should keep a local table of changes to sync when you can go online and may have to implement some form of "merge" logic.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you need to consider.

If your app is read only, you should implement a 'delta sync' logic in your local d. Keep a timestamp of last sync and get updates from your server. Of course, you need to consider the local db size in getting too large.

If you app is read/write, when working offline, you need to consider the two way sync especially when same record can be updated in different devices/users.